# How to print row(s) if they meet a certain range

Tags: python, pandas, awk

I have two mega files that look like below:

f1:

```
chr1,3073253,3074322,gene_id,"ENSMUSG00000102693.1",gene_type,"TEC"
chr1,3074253,3075322,gene_id,"ENSMUSG00000102693.1",transcript_id,"ENSMUST00000193812.1"
chr1,3077253,3078322,gene_id,"ENSMUSG00000102693.1",transcript_id,"ENSMUST00000193812.1"
chr1,3102916,3103025,gene_id,"ENSMUSG00000064842.1",gene_type,"snRNA"
chr1,3105016,3106025,gene_id,"ENSMUSG00000064842.1",transcript_id,"ENSMUST00000082908.1"
```

f2:

```
chr,name,start,end
chr1,linc1320,3073300,3074300
chr3,linc2245,3077270,3078250
chr1,linc8956,4410501,4406025
```

What I want to do is to print the rows of file 2 in a separate column in file 1 IF the range of `start` and `end` column of file2 is inside the ranges in file1 (columns 2 and 3) and `chr` is the same. So based on the dummy example files I provided - the desired output should be (only the range of `linc1320` is in the first row of the file1):

```
chr1,3073253,3074322,gene_id,"ENSMUSG00000102693.1",gene_type,"TEC",linc1320,3073300,3074300
chr1,3074253,3075322,gene_id,"ENSMUSG00000102693.1",transcript_id,"ENSMUST00000193812.1"
chr1,3077253,3078322,gene_id,"ENSMUSG00000102693.1",transcript_id,"ENSMUST00000193812.1"
chr1,3102916,3103025,gene_id,"ENSMUSG00000064842.1",gene_type,"snRNA"
chr1,3105016,3106025,gene_id,"ENSMUSG00000064842.1",transcript_id,"ENSMUST00000082908.1"
```

I am not a professional coder but I have been using this code to manually change the ranges based on the file2:

```
awk -F ',' '$2<=3073300,$3>=3074300, {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' f1.csv
```

I do not have a particular preference for using a specific programming language - both `Python` and `awk` would be very helpful. Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Are you okay with using the pandas library in python or you want the script in core python itself?

Comment: I would like to also have the solution with pandas as well - thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==NR {if (FNR>1) {chr[++n] = $1; id[n]=$2; r1[n]=$3; r2[n]=$4}; next} {for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) if ($1 == chr[i] && r1[i] > $2 && r2[i] < $3) {$0 = $0 OFS id[i] OFS r1[i] OFS r2[i]; break}} 1' file2 file1

chr1,3073253,3074322,gene_id,"ENSMUSG00000102693.1",gene_type,"TEC",linc1320,3073300,3074300
chr1,3074253,3075322,gene_id,"ENSMUSG00000102693.1",transcript_id,"ENSMUST00000193812.1"
chr1,3077253,3078322,gene_id,"ENSMUSG00000102693.1",transcript_id,"ENSMUST00000193812.1"
chr1,3102916,3103025,gene_id,"ENSMUSG00000064842.1",gene_type,"snRNA"
chr1,3105016,3106025,gene_id,"ENSMUSG00000064842.1",transcript_id,"ENSMUST00000082908.1"
```

A more readable form:

```sh
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
FNR == NR {
   if (FNR > 1) {
      chr[++n] = $1
      id[n] = $2
      r1[n] = $3
      r2[n] = $4
   }
   next
}
{
   for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
      if ($1 == chr[i] && r1[i] > $2 && r2[i] < $3) {
         $0 = $0 OFS id[i] OFS r1[i] OFS r2[i]
         break
      }
} 1' file2 file1
```

Comment: thank you - your code works perfectly - Unfortunately, I forgot about a very very important part in my question (updated now) - everything stays the same in the question but I added a column called ```chr``` in the file2 - so the code should run as it is now but before starting for looking at the ranges the code should look at the ```chr``` in the files and if ```chr``` is the same and ranges are inside the file1 then should print output. So now the desired output should be as I updated above. It would be very great if you could help me with this - sorry for any inconveniences.

Comment: ok check updated answer. btw you have `ch1` instead of `chr1` in your sample code which is a typo I think.

Comment: thank you very much for being very helpful - I really appreciate that. Exactly it was a typo, I corrected it.

Answer (score 4):

Let us try approaching the problem `pandas` way, first read the `csv` files into a `pandas` dataframe

```
f1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', header=None)
f2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

>>> f1

      0        1        2        3                     4              5                     6
0  chr1  3073253  3074322  gene_id  ENSMUSG00000102693.1      gene_type                   TEC
1  chr1  3074253  3075322  gene_id  ENSMUSG00000102693.1  transcript_id  ENSMUST00000193812.1
2  chr1  3077253  3078322  gene_id  ENSMUSG00000102693.1  transcript_id  ENSMUST00000193812.1
3  chr1  3102916  3103025  gene_id  ENSMUSG00000064842.1      gene_type                 snRNA
4  chr1  3105016  3106025  gene_id  ENSMUSG00000064842.1  transcript_id  ENSMUST00000082908.1


>>> f2

    chr      name    start      end
0  chr1  linc1320  3073300  3074300
1  chr3  linc2245  3077270  3078250
2  chr1  linc8956  4410501  4406025
```

Now we can `merge` and `filter` the rows which satisfy the given condition of interval inclusion then we can `join` the filtered rows with the file `f1`

```
m = f1.reset_index()\
      .merge(f2, left_on=0, right_on='chr')\
      .where(lambda x: x[1].le(x['start']) & x[2].ge(x['end']))\
      .set_index('index')[['name', 'start', 'end']]

f3 = f1.join(m)
```

---

```
>>> f3

      0        1        2        3                     4              5                     6      name      start        end
0  chr1  3073253  3074322  gene_id  ENSMUSG00000102693.1      gene_type                   TEC  linc1320  3073300.0  3074300.0
1  chr1  3074253  3075322  gene_id  ENSMUSG00000102693.1  transcript_id  ENSMUST00000193812.1       NaN        NaN        NaN
2  chr1  3077253  3078322  gene_id  ENSMUSG00000102693.1  transcript_id  ENSMUST00000193812.1       NaN        NaN        NaN
3  chr1  3102916  3103025  gene_id  ENSMUSG00000064842.1      gene_type                 snRNA       NaN        NaN        NaN
4  chr1  3105016  3106025  gene_id  ENSMUSG00000064842.1  transcript_id  ENSMUST00000082908.1       NaN        NaN        NaN
```

PS: You can also save the resulting dataframe `f3` to a csv file using `f3.to_csv('file3.csv')`

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT:*** With OP's edited Input, one could try following. This will work even fields are more than 4 in file2.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==NR{
  start[++count]=$2
  end[count]=$3
  match($0,/,.*/)
  val[count]=substr($0,RSTART-1,RLENGTH-1)
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    if(start[i]>$2 && end[i]<$3){
      print $0 OFS val[i]
      next
    }
  }
}
1' file2 file1
```

---

---

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`. Taken reference from anubhava's answer.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==NR{
  start[++count]=$2
  end[count]=$3
  val[count]=$0
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    if(start[i]>$2 && end[i]<$3){
      print $0 OFS val[i]
      next
    }
  }
}
1' file2 file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                  ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                 ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=OFS=","                           ##Setting FS and OFS as comma here. 
}
FNR==NR{                               ##Checking condition which will be true when file2 is being read.
  start[++count]=$2                    ##Creating start array with count variable as as index and has $2 value in it.
  end[count]=$3                        ##Creating end array with count as index and value is $3.
  val[count]=$0                        ##Creating val array with index of count and value as $0.
  next                                 ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){               ##Running for loop till value of count here.
    if(start[i]>$2 && end[i]<$3){      ##Checking condition if start[i]>$2 AND end[i]<$3.
      print $0 OFS val[i]              ##Then printing current line with OFS, val here.
      next                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
    }
  }
}
1                                      ##1 will print current line here.
' file2 file1                          ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Thank you for your input - with your code I get only the 1st and 4th roes of the f1 but actually the only the 1st and the 3rd rows of the file1 should be printed since the ranges in the file2 are inside the ranges of the 1st and 3rd rows of the file1.

Comment: it could be great if your code also could writhe the name of the first column (names) of the file2 as a separate column in the output.

Comment: @Apex, could you please confirm once, if you want to compare both files line by line?(I mean by line numbers? OR file2 has only 3 lines which should be taken index of whole file1?) Please confirm once.

Comment: it should not be a line by line comparison - if the ranges in the f2 fall inside the ranges in f1 then the rows of f1 should be printed (``` and names of the rows from f2 as a separate column in the output```)